# Watching TV in the Sukkah?

Tags: sukkah, chol-hamoed, kavod, performance-entertainment

Are there any poseqim that discuss the permissibility or lack thereof of watching TV, or any streaming media really, in the Sukkah?

What is the balance between the principles of תשבו כעין תדורו (that how we live in the Sukkah should approximate/mirror how we live in our homes) and כבוד/קדושת הסוכה (the respect/honor due to the Sukkah as a function of its sanctity) as it relates to this issue?

Of course, for those that forbid watching such media altogether, such discussion would seem to be a non sequitur. I am nevertheless interested in hearing such voices as well, if they exist as related to this topic.

Comment: I think you will struggle to find any piskei halocho for this. Like you say, most prominent Rabbonim would not support the watching of media before you even get to the Succah element. Although, having said that I would imagine they would be fine with ppl watching a shiur in the Succah?

Comment: Pretty sure the rabbis frown down on having sexual relations in the sukkah, so I would assume this too would be frowned down upon

Comment: @CuriousYid On the contrary, that's a mitzva.

Comment: Isn't this טיול? Leisure is done in the sukkah as well. (One should always choose productive leisure activities.)

Comment: @Dov perhaps not from the Haredi sector but I would expect responses from the Dati Leumi / Modern Orthodox sectors. For example Rav Binyamin Bamberger discusses the permissibility of watching TV on Hol ha-Mo'ed [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/35550).

Comment: @CuriousYid no such issue, provided it is private/modest.

Comment: @DoubleAA I personally would think so as well and so conduct myself. Nevertheless, I am interested in learning of any analysis in the literature.